# Вёрстка сложных таблиц

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Каким способом лучше всего сверстать большую адаптивную таблицу? Из классического вида в десктопе под мобильные устройства. Как будет выглядеть логика тегов? Желательно без сторонних библиотек, но можно бутстрап.
[image: Большая таблица]

[image: Маленькая таблица]

Comment: без бутсрапов и библиотек проще всего сделать на [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) да и быстрее и не нужно весь бустраповский мусор подключать.

Comment: @Greg-- да, пожалуй, лучше сделаю на гридах, спасибо за идею

Answer (score 0):

как-нибудь так например

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-md-4">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 order-md-3">счет открыт</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-1 font-weight-bold ">ИП Рога и копыта</div>
    
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-2">ИНН 11111111</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 order-md-0">31 августа <span>11:14</span></div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ещё на десктопе в таблице есть thead, который в мобильной версии скрывается, как можно дополнить код?

Comment: @Игнат `<div class="d-none d-md-block">thead</div>`. Мб почитать надо сначала про бутстрап, если собираетесь его использовать-то?